# Transparent background for WPF Listview Header

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, transparency, tableheader

I wish to create a table using `ListView`.

The background of **table header** must be transparent.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Make your own template for the ListView by modifying the existing one here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates

Comment: Please don't get your friends to upvote your bad questions

Comment: please post some code that you have done.

Comment: Dear musefan, I am not here for votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `Background` of the `ListView` to `Transparent` and define a `GridViewColumnHeader` style that sets its `Background` to `Transparent`:

```
<ListView ...
          Background="Transparent">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn .../>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```